# Java and Javascript regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace the every 4th comma of a string by new line.

In javascript below works good

```
 var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"
 str = str.replace(/(([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)),/g, '$1\n').
```

and gives me right output like below:

blue,red,green,orange,yellow
brown,black,teal,purple,gold
silver

I am trying to do the same in java with

```
String str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver";
str = str.replaceAll("([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)", "$1\n");
```

with output:
orange,
teal,
,gold,silver

Can anyone help me to get the right expression to replace nth(fourth) comma with new line in java

Comment: That's not valid java. It won't compile. Start with that and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: [This Regexr](http://regexr.com/3e81v) reveals the pattern to be working as expected...

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable - Thanks ,I tried this  - (([^,]*,){4} - i see the comma appened in 1st and 2nd line which i dont want.Any clues how to remove that.

Comment: The capture buffer is being overwritten each quantified pass. `([^,]*,){4}` so you only get the last one. What's wrong with using the same regex's?

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript pattern, you have two selection groups that are nested in one selection group, `$1` references the selection-group with the other two selection groups in it.

In the Java pattern, you have two selection-groups, and no other ones, `$1` references to the first selection-group instead of the one that contains the other two as in the JavaScript pattern.

Removing the braces of the first selection-group in JavaScript reproduces the unexpected result, so adding braces around the Java pattern should solve your problem.

**What went wrong**

The first pattern's selection-group sls

**Before**

```
//JavaScript
var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"
str = str.replace(/(([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)),/g, '$1\n').
//Output:
//blue,red,green,orange,yellow
//,brown,black,teal,purple
//,gold,silver

//Java
String str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver";
str = str.replaceAll("([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)", "$1\n");
//Output:
//orange,
//teal,
//,gold,silver
```

[Regexr for Java pattern (not fixed yet)](http://regexr.com/3e822)

**After**

```
//JavaScript
var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"
str = str.replace(/(([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)),/g, '$1\n').
//Output:
//blue,red,green,orange,yellow
//,brown,black,teal,purple
//,gold,silver

//Java
String str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver";
str = str.replaceAll("(([^,]*,){4}([^,]*)),", "$1\n");
// These were added --^------------------^^
//Output:
//blue,red,green,orange,yellow
//,brown,black,teal,purple
//,gold,silver
```

[Regexr for Java pattern (fixed)](http://regexr.com/3e81v)

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation.(([^,]*,){4}).I tried this - (([^,]*,){4}) - i see the comma appened at the end  in 1st and 2nd line which i dont want.Any clues how to remove that.

Comment: @Vinu Sorry, i missed the comma behind the first, working pattern. I updated my answer